# Yocto image is not adding the files to rootfs

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I want to create a new folder in "/etc", as following

```
/etc
----/shared
-----------example.txt
```

I created a new recipe in a custom yocto layer. The recipe is under a folder `meta-own\recipes-own\shared` and the structure of `recipes-own` is:

```
.
├── files
│   ├── example.txt
└── shared_configuration_1.0.bb
```

and the recipe is:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Script for copying example configurations"
SUMMARY = "example configurations"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://example.txt"

do_install_append() {
    install -dm644 ${D}${sysconfdir}/shared
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/example.txt ${D}${sysconfdir}/example.txt

FILES_${PN} = "\
    ${sysconfdir} \
"
```

When I add the recipe to my `recipes-core/images/example-image.bb`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
    bash \
    util-linux \
    shared_configuration \
    "
```

it outputs me always:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES
```

But if I don't place it in the example-image, it is running through but the file is not copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rename shared_configuration  to shared-configuration because after the underscore should be the version of the recipe.

[EDIT]

```
.
├── files
│   ├── example.txt
└── shared-configuration_1.0.bb
```

---

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
    bash \
    util-linux \
    shared-configuration \
    "
```

And the recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Script for copying example configurations"
SUMMARY = "example configurations"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://example.txt"

do_install_append() {
    install -d 644 ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/example.txt ${D}${sysconfdir}

FILES_${PN} = "${sysconfdir}"
```

Comment: It was the naming of the recipe. Use dash instead of underscore. Thanks.